# Rotate a point around another point

Tags: c#, rotation, gdi, trigonometry

I have a task to draw a specific graphic. As part of this task I need to rotate some dot's on 45 degrees.

I've spent already 2 days trying to calculate a formula, but just couldn't get it right.
I've been searching all over the place including this particular website, I'm getting very close, but I'm still not there.

Here it is:
I need to draw 4 different points

I have a specific formula to calculate there position, which is out of scope of the question, but here is what I'm getting as a result of it:

```
int radius = 576;
int diameter = radius * 2;
Point blueA = new Point(561, 273);
Point greenB = new Point(273, 561);
Point yellowC = new Point (849, 561);
Point redD = new Point (561, 849);
```

[image: result]

Now I need to rotate this dots on 45 degrees. I use the following code to achieve it:

```
double rotationAngle = 45;
double rotationRadians = rotationAngle * (Math.PI / 180);
int center = radius;    
result.X = (int)(Math.Cos(rotationRadians) * ((double)result.X - (double)center) - (double)Math.Sin(rotationRadians) * ((double)result.Y - center) + (double)center);
result.Y = (int)(Math.Sin(rotationRadians) * ((double)result.X - (double)center) + (double)Math.Cos(rotationRadians) * ((double)result.Y - center) + (double)center);
```

But that's what I'm getting:

[image: Result]

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem is `int center = radius` which you are setting `int radius = 576`. This doesn't make sense as surely you are rotating about a point that  should have an x and y location.

Given you are rotating around the origin the center `x` and `y` should both be `0` not `576`.

So, given that, try this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Rotates one point around another
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pointToRotate">The point to rotate.</param>
/// <param name="centerPoint">The center point of rotation.</param>
/// <param name="angleInDegrees">The rotation angle in degrees.</param>
/// <returns>Rotated point</returns>
static Point RotatePoint(Point pointToRotate, Point centerPoint, double angleInDegrees)
{
    double angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    double cosTheta = Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
    double sinTheta = Math.Sin(angleInRadians);
    return new Point
    {
        X =
            (int)
            (cosTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) -
            sinTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.X),
        Y =
            (int)
            (sinTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) +
            cosTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.Y)
    };
}
```

Use like so.

```
Point center = new Point(0, 0); 
Point newPoint = RotatePoint(blueA, center, 45);
```

Obviously if the center point is always `0,0` then you can simplify the function accordingly, or else make the center point optional via a default parameter, or by overloading the method. You would also probably want to encapsulate some of the reusable math into other static methods too.

e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts an angle in decimal degress to radians.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="angleInDegrees">The angle in degrees to convert.</param>
/// <returns>Angle in radians</returns>
static double DegreesToRadians(double angleInDegrees)
{
   return angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}

/// <summary>
/// Rotates a point around the origin
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pointToRotate">The point to rotate.</param>
/// <param name="angleInDegrees">The rotation angle in degrees.</param>
/// <returns>Rotated point</returns>
static Point RotatePoint(Point pointToRotate, double angleInDegrees)
{
   return RotatePoint(pointToRotate, new Point(0, 0), angleInDegrees);
}
```

Use like so.

```
Point newPoint = RotatePoint(blueA, 45);
```

Finally, if you are using the GDI you can also simply do a `RotateTransform`.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662.aspx

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.TranslateTransform(blueA);
g.RotateTransform(45);
```

Comment: it is perfect! Thank you.
Here is the current screenshot:
http://s8.postimage.org/e7r44klcl/result.png

Comment: You are right. A contributor to an OS lib must have hand copied this because the parenthesis were screwed up and it came out wrong in the unit tests.

Comment: Could someone point to a resource to understand the equations in `RotatePoint`?

Comment: @BryceGuinta It is just basic trig - https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trigonometry-index.html

Comment: I used this formula to figure out the angle needed to rotate something to a fixed position by solving for theta and setting the left hand of the equation to the value I want. For `x=0` this formula is `Math.Atan2(pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y, centerPoint.X - pointToRotate.Y)`. Note that the regular atan does not work for all quadrants, so Atan2 is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're math looks weird to me.  I think dx = r*Cos(theta) and dy = r*Sin(theta).

Here's a little program I wrote because this was bothering me, and I haven't done math is years.

```
Point center = new Point() { X = 576, Y = 576 };

Point previous = new Point() { X = 849, Y=561 };
double rotation = 45;
double rotationRadians = rotation * (Math.PI / 180);

//get radius based on the previous point and r squared = a squared + b squared
double r = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(previous.X - center.X, 2) + Math.Pow(previous.Y - center.Y, 2));
Console.WriteLine("r = " + r.ToString());

//calculate previous angle
double previousAngle = Math.Atan((previous.Y - center.Y) / (previous.X - center.X));
Console.WriteLine("Previous angle: " + previousAngle.ToString());

double newAngle = previousAngle + rotationRadians;

Point newP = new Point();
newP.X = center.X + r * Math.Cos(newAngle);
newP.Y = center.Y + r * Math.Sin(newAngle);

Console.WriteLine("(" + newP.X.ToString() + ", " + newP.Y.ToString() + ")");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I use the method in different parts of the code and at some stage I got the "previous" point with these coordinates: X = 576 Y = 20.

In this case I'm getting the "DivideByZeroException"
Here is the result if I put the "try -> catch" block in: http://s10.postimage.org/azjdc7rex/exception.png

Answer (score 0):

Rotate a point in a class `

```
public Koordinat DondurNoktaEtrafinda(Koordinat dondurmeMerkezi, double 
        dondurmeAcisiRadyan)
       {
       double cosAngle = Math.Cos(dondurmeAcisiRadyan); double sinAngle = 
 Math.Sin(dondurmeAcisiRadyan); 
      double newX = cosAngle * (X - dondurmeMerkezi.X) - sinAngle * (Y -dondurmeMerkezi.Y) + dondurmeMerkezi.X;
      double newY = sinAngle * (X - dondurmeMerkezi.X) + cosAngle * (Y -dondurmeMerkezi.Y) + dondurmeMerkezi.Y;
      double newZ = Z;

      return new Koordinat(newX, newY, newZ);
  }`
```