# How to simulate pendulum movement with high amplitude in C#

Tags: c#, math, physics, computational-geometry, differential-equations

I need to make a C# simulator for a simple pendulum.
I have been searching the web for 3 days and I am stuck.

The problem is I have found many equations that would give the angle position as a function of time, which is perfect for my needs for making a visual simulation but the problem is those functions only works for angles smaller than 10, but I should be able to simulate from any angle.
Example of a equation that only works for small angles:

Source: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pend.html#c2

And the equations that should work for any angle (Amplitude) are too complicated as it involves differential equations, and derivatives. I don't know how to implement these in C#.
Example of a equation that I think would work but I don't know how to use:

Source: http://www.sbfisica.org.br/rbef/pdf/070707.pdf
(Equation number 32)

the problem of this last equation is the "sn" that is Jacobi elliptic function sn(u;m) u, and I don't know how to use in C#

Can someone help? maybe with another equation that I could use programmatically, or helping me understand how I could use this last one if it would really works.

Comment: Could also just [rotate a position around an origin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13695317/1218281), not that difficult. (But relying on trigonometry and not actual physics)

Comment: It would not work as the simulator has to accept any Pendulum length and any mass, and any starting angle.

Comment: There is a good article at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566614/Elliptic-integrals which looks at exactly this problem, and ends up approximating the elliptic integral with a Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *simulate* the pendulum, you don't need the exact solution. The only you need is a sufficiently good approximation at every step of your simulation, combined with sufficient steps. This is similar to approximating a circle with a sufficiently large number of segments, each of them, tangent to the ideal circle.

Now, consider your pendulum has a deviation of `theta` degrees (or radians) from the vertical as depicted below:

[image]

The mass `m` will have a weight of `m * g`, where `g` is the gravity acceleration. Now, let's approximate the angle `alpha` where the pendulum will move in the next `dt` seconds (`dt` is the duration of one step, so `dt` is just a fraction of a second).

Since the acceleration on the tangent direction is `g * cos(theta)` we can approximate the tangent distance the pendulum would travel in `dt` seconds as if the acceleration were constant during this lapse:

```
d = v * dt + g * sin(theta) (dt)^2 / 2
```

where `v` is the tangential speed of the pendulum at the angular position `theta.` Now we can calculate `alpha` as

```
alpha = arcsin(d / r)
```

where `r` is the radius. Thus, the only that remains is to update the value of `v` so we can repeat the same in the next step. Here is how

```
v := v + g * sin(theta) * dt
```

Of course, when the pendulum starts you can initialize `v = 0`.

I haven't tried this myself, so please, let me know if this "simulated" approach worked for you. Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly the approach given in his "methods that only work for small angles" link.

Comment: Yes, but with a difference. In my (it isn't "mine" but..) approach the total angle `theta` doesn't have to be small, it can be anything. Only the differential `alpha` must be small, which requires `dt` to be small enough. The effect is the discretization of the movement into small steps where the mathematical equations are simple and easy to solve.